# How to create a Tabulator object that uses another html file element?

Tags: javascript, electron, tabulator

I'm currently creating an electron desktop application to open another window when I double-click on a cell from a tabulator element displayed in HTML. I would like to create another tabulator table in the new window, however since I am loading a new HTML file it doesn't recognize any of the elements, thus I can't define the tabulator object like so...

```
var rules_table = new Tabulator("#the-new-htmlfile-div", {data: rowData, maxHeight:"100%", autoColumns:true});
```

results in...

Tabulator Creation Error - no element found matching selector:  #the-new-htmlfile-div

any ideas on how to fix this?